# HasFrame is returning 0 and I don't understand why

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I'm trying to read through the frames of a .avi video and find the circles in each one, but for some reason the hasFrame method keeps returning 0, even when the CurrentTime property is set to 0, or 1, or another value I know is contained in the 90 second long video.

```
vid = VideoReader('2nd try-1-gazeoverlay.avi');
fps = vid.FrameRate;
dur = vid.Duration;

while hasFrame(vid)
next = frame2im(readFrame(vid));
rgb = imread(next);
figure
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(rgb,[45 55],'ObjectPolarity','bright', 'Sensitivity', 0.92, 'Method', 'twostage');
imshow(rgb);
h = viscircles(centers,radii);
end
```

The while loop never runs, and when I call hasFrame on vid in the command window it returns 0.

Help?

Comment: Do `fps` and `dur` contain the expected values? How are you determining that the `while` loop is not running? Where are you testing `hasFrame`?

Comment: Can you use `whos vid` to double check that VideoReader recognize that video.

Comment: Yes, 'fps' and 'dur' contain the expected values.  'whos vid' returns that it is indeed of the class VideoReader.  It turns out it was some type of codec problem though, and it works when I convert it to .mp4 rather than .avi.  Thanks.